# Draw a Line Chart with both solid and dotted line in it with angular nvd3js directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives, angular-nvd3

I'm using angular-nvd3 directive for making a custom line chart display counting number of guest in specific period time range as follow :

1. **current Time - 2 --> current Time** : will be display as ***straight line***
2. **current Time --> current Time + 2** : will be display as ***dotted line*** .

Here is my implementation code with only straight line:

```html
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                tooltips: false,
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                y: function(d){ return d.y; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: false,
                dispatch: {
                    stateChange: function(e){ console.log("stateChange"); },
                    changeState: function(e){ console.log("changeState"); },
                    tooltipShow: function(e){ console.log("tooltipShow"); },
                    tooltipHide: function(e){ console.log("tooltipHide"); }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Time (ms)'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Voltage (v)',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format('.02f')(d);
                    },
                    axisLabelDistance: 30
                },
                callback: function(chart){
                    console.log("!!! lineChart callback !!!");
                }
            },
            title: {
                enable: true,
                text: 'Title for Line Chart'
            }
            
        };

        $scope.data = sinAndCos();

        /*Random Data Generator */
        function sinAndCos() {
            var sin = [],sin2 = [],
                cos = [];

            //Data is represented as an array of {x,y} pairs.
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
                sin2.push({x: i, y: i % 10 == 5 ? null : Math.sin(i/10) *0.25 + 0.5});
                cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10+ 2) + Math.random() / 10});
            }

            //Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
            return [
                {
                    values: [{x:7,y:100},{x:8,y:40},{x:9,y:70}],      
                    key: 'Sine Wave', //key  - the name of the series.
                    color: '#ff7f0e',  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
                    strokeWidth: 2    
                },
                {
                
                    values: [{x:7,y:200},{x:8,y:140},{x:9,y:170},{x:10,y:120},{x:11,y:180}],
                    key: 'Cosine Wave',
                    color: '#2ca02c'
                },
                {
                    values: [{x:7,y:300},{x:8,y:240},{x:9,y:270},{x:10,y:220},{x:11,y:280}],
                    key: 'Another sine wave',
                    color: '#7777ff'    
                }
            ];
        };
});
```

Here is the plunker for this : http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview

Anyone can provide some help that would get my great appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
            

{
            
                values: [{x:7,y:200},{x:8,y:140},{x:9,y:170},{x:10,y:120},{x:11,y:180}],
                key: 'Cosine Wave',
                color: '#2ca02c',
                classed: 'dashed'  // <-- Now use CSS to make the line dashed
            }

STYLE!!!

.dashed {
            stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
        }
```